# Errors in APT output after installing Python packages and running update-alternatives

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python, dpkg

I installed biopython and python 3.5 and set it as default with

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy
sudo apt-get install python3-biopython
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 2
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 2
```

everything worked good but now -- all of a sudden after having installed other stuff successfully I'm getting a failure when installing font-manager:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f 
[sudo] password...: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python-biopython (1.66+dfsg-1build1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-biopython (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-libxml2 (2.9.3+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-libxml2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-biopython
 python-libxml2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now, I know that the `Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` has been posted several times, but each time the answer is specific to the broken package.

I tried to remove python-biopython and libxml2 but I can't install or remove anything now due to this broken package. Neither Synaptic could solve the problem.

I would rather skip the reinstalling the whole operative system, so is there a solution that I can apply?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the default version if your python default version to python2.
do:

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
```

check your current default python by:

```
python --version
```

Then to check the list of python version

```
 update-alternatives --list python
```

Then do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
```

Then do:

```
 update-alternatives --list python
```

Then do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Then select the python version 2 and then do:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```